# How to Add Scroll Feature in REACT NATIVE PAPER using Menu.Item

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I need Scrollable in DropDown in React Native Paper using Menu.Item.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Menu component in a ScrollView, like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <Menu...>
    .
    .
    .
    <\Menu>
</ScollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this for future reference, but instead of wrapping the `<Menu>` element in a `ScrollView`, wrap the inside of the Menu, where the `Menu.Item`s will appear in a ScrollView, that's how I got it to work.

Something like:

```
<Menu>
  <ScrollView>
    ...   
  </ScrollView>
</Menu>
```